# Python Socket Wireless scan strange output

Tags: python, sockets, wireless

i have this code here:

```
import socket
raw = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(0x0003))
raw.bind(("mon0", 0x0003))
ap_list = set()
out = open("out.cap", 'w')
while True:
    pkt = raw.recvfrom(2048)[0]
        if pkt[36:42] not in ap_list:
            ap_list.add(pkt[36:42])
            print (pkt)
            out.writelines(str(pkt))
```

but the output is kinda strange to me. how to make it Human readable?

Example of output:

```
b'\x00!c\xf60\xbe\x807s\xa8\xe5@\x08\x00E\x00\x004\xea\xec@\x00$\x06\xd2\xcck\x15mA\xc0\xa8\x00\x0c\x00P\x90\xee\x9dx\xd9E=\xfd;[\x80\x10\x00no\xc0\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n)\xa0w\x10\x00\xd6J\xa8'
```

Update:
using this

```
decoded = pkt.decode("ISO-8859-1")
```

i've managed to do what i need but wireshark don't read my output file very well and i also need to remove useless data from the output

some help?

this is the new code:

```
import socket
import sys

raw = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(0x0003))
raw.bind((sys.argv[1], 0x0003))
ap_list = set()
out = open("out.cap", 'w')
while True:
    pkt = raw.recvfrom(1024)[0]
    if pkt[36:42] not in ap_list:
        ap_list.add(pkt[36:42])
        decoded = pkt.decode("ISO-8859-1")
        print(str(pkt[0:20]).split("'")[1])
        out.writelines(str(decoded) + "\n")
```

Comment: What does the output look like now?

Comment: a pkt printed on the terminal looks like: **;ÛÄ6´áÄz~ {y [...]**

and outputted in a file and opened in sublime looks like: 

**c398 04c3 8b79 5620 00c2 81c3 8436 c290 [...]**

Comment: What protocol do you think that is?  Why do you expect it to be human-readable?

Comment: I know is not human readable, i use wireshark to read it but sometimes he doesn't want to load the output...

I have seen some code online and people have managed to extract some sort of information like MAC Address or stuff like that, i was wondering if could do the same with this, in wireshark i saw some info about visited web page but how do i extract those info?

Comment: In Wireshark you should be able to see what protocols are being used.  Then you can parse them, for example using the `scapy` package.

Comment: Thanks, with scapy is much easier, just six lines of code and it's all done

Answer (score 0):

In Wireshark you should be able to see what protocols are being used.  Then you can parse them, for example using the `scapy` package.
                    – John Zwinck